# Can I turn a Django form into a GET request string?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to take a ready-made form (i.e an object of a class derived from `django.Forms.form` with validated bound data) and urlencode it as though it were submitted with GET. Is there a built-in way?

To show why I'm asking this questino, and why I can't just call `urlencode`, the output from this should be "`box=on`".

```
from django import forms
from urllib import urlencode


class DemoForm(forms.Form):
    box = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

instance = DemoForm({"box": True})  # it's irrelevant how this data is supplied
instance.is_valid()
print "encoded:", urlencode(instance.cleaned_data)
```

In fact it's "`box=True`", because `urlencode` isn't encoding the form it's encoding the cleaned values (and believe me, `BooleanField` is the simplest case).

So I'm asking for a way to encode the form as though it were a GET string. A correct GET string.

Answer (score 5):

Calling urllib's urlencode on the form's cleaned_data won't work well in two cases:

- If you are using a ModelChoiceField, the cleaned_data will contain the actual object(s), not the IDs.  These will urlencode() to their string representations instead of their primary keys.
- If you are using a field that can hold multiple values (such as MultiValueField, MultipleChoiceField or others), urlencode() will lose all but one value from that field.  So {'mykey':[1,2,3]} becomes ?mykey=3 instead of ?mykey=1&mykey=2&mykey=3 the way django does it.

To deal with both of these problems, use the form's built-in urlencode function:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST) #or a dict or whatever
form.is_valid()
querystring = form.data.urlencode()
```

Note that this is called on data, not cleaned_data.  If your form changes values as part of validation, those changes won't be reflected here.

Comment: This works really well, thanks.  Note that if the data from the form was generated by POST, it will probably have a csrfmiddlewaretoken, which should probably be stripped out.

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this nowadays, this is apparently no longer supported in Django 1.10 and above. `from django.utils.http import urlencode; querystring = urlencode(form.data, doseq=True)`

Will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully sure what you mean with ready-made form, since a form will normally have no values associated. Or do you mean to take a form a user filled and have it posted as a get?

You can use urllibs encode to create a get-string:

```
import urllib

print urllib.urlencode({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
# key1=value1&key2=value2
```

If you want to take a posted form and create a GET-string from this data:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    print urllib.urlencode(form.cleaned_data)
    # name=value&name=value etc
```

If you want to create a GET for an unbound form:

```
# this form contains intitial values
# which are shown when printing the form
form = MyForm()
print urllib.urlencode(form.initial)
# name=value&name=value etc
```

Comment: By ready-made I mean an instance of a form class derived form `django.Forms.form`. I'll clarify the question. I know how to build a GET string with my own dictionary, I want to do it from a validated form based on its fields.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit lost in exactly when in the "flow" of the form this is suppose to happend but I've updated my response with a few more examples.

Comment: Let's say I have a validated form with bound data (i.e. I have called `is_valid` and the response is `True`). This has been constructed and initialised from data. This could be initial data supplied in the constructor, it could be from POST data, it could be from anything. It doesn't matter how this form object was created. I want to produce a GET url encoded string that represents how the form would be submitted if I submitted it from a browser.

Comment: I'm afraid form.cleaned_data includes object lookups etc so it's not suitable for passing to `urlencode` (e.g. a checkbox is True in Python but the URL should show 'on').

Comment: I'm sorry I thought the question was clear, I've added an example to illustrate.

Comment: If you could construct the get-string manually, how would it look?

Comment: As per example, it should look like `box=on`. And if the box value were false it would be an empty string.